# Remove/Update a list in Clojure

Tags: list, clojure

I'm giving a function two args, an element f to remove from a list and the collection. (the collection is also an atom)

```
 (defn playCard [f coll]
  (let [c (first (filter f @coll))] 
    (println coll)
    (println c)
    (swap! ((remove #{c} #{coll}) @coll)) ;;here
    (println coll)
    (println "DIVIDER")

    ))
```

I can successfully get f. But when I attempt to remove it from the list I receive the error: "ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn".

Throughout my work I receive errors similar to this one often. I'm unsure of how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

The structures being dealt with are:

A hash map of the available cards:

```
(def cards
  (hash-map
    :card1 {:name "Wisp" :damage 1 :health 1 :cost 0 :charge "t"}
    :card2 {:name "Spider Tank" :damage 3 :health 4 :cost 3}
    :card3 {:name "Boulder Fist Ogre" :damage 6 :health 7 :cost 6})
 )
```

A list of these cards (the hand):

```
(def hand1
      (list (get cards :card1) (get cards :card2) (get cards :card3) (get cards :card1)))
```

The playCard function is being given a card name and a hand.

Comment: Why are you passing in coll, then making it an atom that you immediately deref?  Then you deref it again as d? Do you just want to remove an item from a collection?

Comment: At some point I began tossing in extra variables in desperation. But yes, I do want to remove an item from a collection. That collection is defined as an atom elsewhere however.

Comment: `#{coll}` seems odd to me. Maybe you could start without an atom and just do a remove, and build things up from there...

Answer (score 0):

Clojure's [`remove`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/remove) takes a function or a set and a collection.  Here you can see a basic remove function on a basic collection (a vector) using a function.

```
user=> (def coll [0 1 2 3])
#'user/coll
user=> (remove #(> % 2) coll)
(0 1 2)
user=> (remove #(= % 2) coll)
(0 1 3)
```

Or you can pass in a set to match the items you want to remove from the coll:

```
user=> (remove #{2} coll)
(0 1 3)
```

If you've got an atom, you can just deref it when you need its value.

```
user=> (def coll (atom [0 1 2 3]))
#'user/coll
```

Notice that when you just call coll, you don't get the value:

```
user=> coll
#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x7c5e9122 {:status :ready, :val [0 1 2 3]}]
```

But you do when you deref it:

```
user=> @coll
[0 1 2 3]
```

So now you can just pass that in to your remove function, et voila.

```
user=> (remove #(= % 2) @coll)
(0 1 3)
```

Comment: `remove` will happily take a set as the function, so there is nothing wrong with `#{c}`, in fact it is quite possibly the idiomatic way to use `remove`

Comment: Added to my answer.  Thanks for that addition, @ChrisMurphy.

Comment: I follow the answer but I still have a problem. The element I wish to remove is c. I have no idea hot to apply the function to get c to the remove function. I tried (remove (first (filter f @coll) @coll) and nothing happened.

Comment: What is "c" here?  Expand your question to include what data structures or functions you are passing in for `f` and `coll`.

Comment: Best not to use `f` as the name of anything that isn't a function. If you work your way through the https://www.4clojure.com/ problems you will get to see other peoples code. Maybe post another question just on the remove problem. This question lots of issues so too difficult to answer in a direct way.